# Execution failed on equal sign "=" in python

Tags: python, list

I'm a beginner in python and during practicing stuck in the code of reassigning values:

```
##Task to take the first letter of each word and place it at the end of a word, except "special characters", like "!"

entries = "I love Python, its awesome !";

transformed = entrens.split(' ') 

print(len(transformed))

for x in transformed:
    if x.isalpha():
        print(x[0], x[-1] = '', (x[-1] + x[0]) )
    else:
        x
print(transformed)
```

Output:

```
$python main.py
  File "main.py", line 13
    print(x[0], x[-1] = '', (x[-1] + x[0]) )
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How possible to reassign value in one line? Grateful for feedback and support

Comment: Why are you doing an assignment there? That's invalid syntax, it's not allowed. The `=` notation within a function call is for arguments only, not assignments, like `a=1` means *argument `a` has value `1`*.

Comment: You could use colons `;`

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Python assignment is a *statement* (essentially, it is the top level operation for a line), while the arguments to functions must be *expressions* (components of a statement). It's the same reason you can't do assignment in `if`/`while` conditionals.

It's doubly illegal here, because `str` is immutable; you can't modify specific indices. Even as a line by itself `x[-1] = ''` is illegal when `x` is a `str`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following.

```
entries = "I love Python, its awesome !";

transformed = entries.split(' ') # spelling error
print(len(transformed))

for x in transformed:
    if x.isalpha():
        print(x[0], x[-1], (x[-1] + x[0]) ) # delet =''
    else:
        x
print(transformed)
```